# How can I add condition clause not required if element?

Tags: mybatis, mybatis-mapper, mybatis-sql

Let's say I have an interface look like this.

```java
@Mapper
interface UserMapper {
    List<User> search(@Nullable String namePattern, int minAge); 
}
```

How can I do with the `minAge` parameter which is not required the `<if/>` element?

Should I just do with `<if test="true"/>`?

```xml
<where>
  <if test="namePattern != null">
    name LIKE #{namePattern}
  </if>
  <if test="true"> <!-- just true??? -->
    AND age >= #{minAge}
  </if>
</where>
```

Can I peel the second `<if/>` element?

```xml
<where>
  <if test="namePattern != null">
    name LIKE #{namePattern}
  </if>
  AND age >= #{minAge} <!-- will it blend? -->
</where>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. `<where />` removes unnecessary `AND`, so it should work.

Another approach is to write the `age` condition in front of `<if />`s.

```xml
WHERE age >= #{minAge}
<if test="namePattern != null">
  AND name LIKE #{namePattern}
</if>
```